# Collection time out in solrcloud

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet, solrcloud

Hi Am getting following exception while creating collection in SolrCloud.My zookeeper & solr nodes are up.I am able to access solr UI also.

2015-07-23 14:59:01,049 ERROR [solr.core.SolrCore] - [http-8080-1] : org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: delete the collection time out:180s
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:237)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:168)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How to resolve this issue?Tried to restart zookeeper & solr nodes but invain.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake! While starting solr nodes I gave same value for property "-Dhost" for each solr nodes because of which things were not working as expected.

I restarted solr nodes using different values for each node.Everything is working fine now.

Hope it will save someone's time.